# Submitting form with angularjs select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I am very new to angularjs and have replaced a regular html `<select>` box with an angular modal select box.

The select box is populated with a $http ajax request and loads data fine, but the form fails to submit.

My original code:

```
<body>
<form id="form-filename">
<div align="center"><select name="filename" id="filename" class="browser-default"></select></div>
<input type="button" id="submit-filename" value="Apply"><br>
</form></body>
```

My version with the angular select box:

```
<body ng-app="httptest" ng-controller="getjson">
 <form id="form-filename">
 <button class="semi-transparent-button"  name="filename" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="data" modal-title="Select Location">  Select File
                <div class="option">
                  {{option}}
                </div></form>
```

I'm not sure what I need to modify to get the select box to submit the form and update the filename value.

Comment: What does "fail" mean in your case?

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and use the [ng-submit directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you submit a form the Angular way:

**View:**

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="submit(data)">
  <select name="selectElem" ng-model="data.selectedItem" ng-options="item as item for item in options">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Option</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.options = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D'
];

$scope.submit = function(data) {
  // do stuff with your data
  console.log(data);
};
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4a7GMuYceoN038imBV74?p=preview)